# MYSQL : LEFT JOIN run slowly

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join, explain

I have two tables :

[table 1](http://pastebin.com/v4u21W2c)

[table 2](http://pastebin.com/6NVSFD0a)

then I do left join to both tables:

```
SELECT DATE(`Inspection_datetime`) AS Date, `Line`,`Model`, `Lot_no`, 
       COUNT(A.`Serial_number`) AS Qty,B.`name`
FROM `inspection_report` AS A
LEFT JOIN `Employee` AS B
ON A.`NIK` LIKE B.NIK
GROUP BY Date , A.Model ,A.Lot_no,A.Line,B.`name`
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

This query make my Jquery DataTable plugin run very slow even the data not show. The strange point is at this field `B.name`, if I mention it in query the data won't appear but if I delete it, the data would appear (I mean not doing `LEFT JOIN`).

Whether my query not good enough? this my `EXPLAIN`:

```
TABLE 1

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  inspection_report   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    334518  

TABLE 2
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
    1   SIMPLE  Employee    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    100 

QUERY
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  B   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    100 Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  A   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    334520  Using where; Using join buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

Any special reason you are joining with a `LIKE` clause instead of equality?

```
SELECT DATE(`Inspection_datetime`) AS Date, `Line`,`Model`, `Lot_no`, 
       COUNT(A.`Serial_number`) AS Qty,B.`name`
FROM `inspection_report` AS A
LEFT JOIN `Employee` AS B
ON A.`NIK` = B.NIK
GROUP BY Date , A.Model ,A.Lot_no,A.Line,B.`name`
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

should yield better results.

Also, adding an index to A.NIK should help the join operation tremendously.

```
CREATE INDEX inspection_report_nik ON inspection_report (NIK);
```

Comment: I've tried your answer, then try it in my phpmyadmin then it works faster. But, it still not appear at my datatable (at my firebug no error).

Comment: Then your issue may be with the plugin. We need to see the javascript and any server side code you have